# How to fix Http-Server npm command issue?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, httpserver, angular-cli-v7

I've tried to deploy the angular application in my local, I've done the npm-build and got dist, then i tried to execute the http-server command i receive the below error.

changed the port number, cleared the cache, closed and opened the cmd, restarted the machine.

What i need change.

I've tried with new simple project and downloaded one boilerplate from github and my existing project, for all the three projects i received the below error.

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://--.--.---.--:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event     ^

Error: read EINVAL
    at TTY.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: `ng serve` isn't enough ? just curious that why using http-server

Comment: Thank you.. ng serve is working fine, but any guesses for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its always better to use angular cli command `ng serve` for building/running angular apps.

However if you want to use `http-server`, you need to run the command for the output folder path of project. My default it will be `dist`.

Run below 2 commands:

```
ng build
http-server ./dist
```

`ng build` required to build all your source code and then populate dist folder. Then you can run `http-server` for running it.